# How to exit from nested for loop using break statement in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops, break

[tmp.py]

```
#is_skip = False             # Alt. approach
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        if j == 2:
#            is_skip = True  # Alt. approach
            break
        print('I, J => ', i, j)
#    if is_skip:             # Alt. approach
#        break               # Alt. approach
```

[Expected]

```
I, J =>  0 0
I, J =>  0 1
```

[Current]

```
I, J =>  0 0
I, J =>  0 1
I, J =>  1 0
I, J =>  1 1
I, J =>  2 0
I, J =>  2 1
I, J =>  3 0
I, J =>  3 1
I, J =>  4 0
I, J =>  4 1
```

Any other best approach is available, except the above commented one.

Thanks,

Comment: Use `return`  instead

Comment: Use `range(2)` instead of `range(5)`. Sorry, but your example is so contrived that it becomes unclear...

Comment: @Guy `if j == 2: return None` => compile error `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: Of course, when we say  `return` you should put that in a function. Shouldn't that go without saying?

Comment: @JaiK Just `return`, without `None`. All the code should be in a function.

Answer (score 0):

make a function and then return from that when condition matches:

```
def loopBreakExample():
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(3):
            if j == 2:

                return
            print('I, J => ', i, j)
loopBreakExample()
```